# Why does datetime.utcnow not behave as I'd expect with freezegun?

Tags: python, datetime, freezegun

I've noticed something which I don't understand, and I'm wondering if anyone could shed some light on it.

In short: if

- `x = datetime.datetime.utcnow`

and

- `y = lambda: datetime.datetime.utcnow()`

I would expect `x()` and `y()` to behave the same, always.  However, this is apparently not the case when freezegun gets involved - it freezes `y` but not `x`, and I'm wondering why. (This is true if `x` and `y` are defined outside a freezegun context, anyway; inside such a context, they do behave identically, it seems.)

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import freezegun

# I'd expect these two to behave the same, always.
x = datetime.utcnow
y = lambda: datetime.utcnow()

with freezegun.freeze_time('2019-01-02 03:04:05'):
    # Here their behaviours diverge
    print('Time from x:', x())
    print('Time from y:', y())

    # This behaves as I'd expect, however.
    z = datetime.utcnow
    print('Time from z:', z())))
```

Results:

```
Time from x: 2019-10-18 12:21:37.508590
Time from y: 2019-01-02 03:04:05
Time from z: 2019-01-02 03:04:05
```

Here `Time from x` is the time at the moment this is run, i.e it's not under the control of freezegun.

Can anyone shed any light on this? It is just some weirdness of freezegun, or am I misunderstanding something more fundamental about python when I assume that `x` and `y` should be always equivalent? I see that `utcnow` is a bound class method, but I don't get why that would imply this behaviour.

---

#### Postscript: `time.time` doesn't behave this way

Looking at [`utcnow()`'s source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py#L1696) it's basically just a wrapper around `time.time()` — but `time.time` and `lambda: time.time()` **don't** diverge in this way...  So I'm guessing this *does* have something to do with `utcnow()` being a bound class methiod — but I don't know what.

```
import time
import freezegun

r = time.time
s = lambda: time.time()

print('Time outside freezegun:', time.time())
with freezegun.freeze_time('2019-01-02 03:04:05'):
    print('Time from r:', r())
    print('Time from s:', s())
```

gives:

```
Time outside freezegun: 1571401765.2612312
Time from r: 1546398245.0
Time from s: 1546398245.0
```

---

#### Versions in play

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3

$ pip list | grep freezegun
freezegun               0.3.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I'm guessing this does have something to do with utcnow() being a bound class methiod — but I don't know what.

Looks like your intuition is correct. Freezegun doesn't patch individual methods of `datetime` class - instead [it replaces the class entirely](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/blob/0.3.12/freezegun/api.py#L577) with its own `FakeDatetime` class.

By doing the assignment:

```
x = datetime.utcnow
```

x stores reference to the original `utcnow()` method, which stays the same even inside `freezegun.freeze_time()` context manager.

On the other hand `lambda: datetime.utcnow()` calls `utcnow()` on `datetime` class which is available in current context, and that is `FakeDatetime` patched by `freezegun.freeze_time()`.

`time.time()` is [patched by freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/blob/0.3.12/freezegun/api.py#L580) with `fake_time()`. Freezegun even searches through loaded modules and [patches variables](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/blob/0.3.12/freezegun/api.py#L618) storing reference to `time.time()`, but it's limited to module variables so e.g. it doesn't check inside lists:

```
import time
import freezegun

r = [time.time]

with freezegun.freeze_time('2019-01-02 03:04:05'):
    print('Time inside freezegun:', time.time())
    time_inside_list = r[0]
    print('Time from list:', time_inside_list())
```

output:

```
Time inside freezegun: 1546398245.0
Time from list: 1571669871.8807676
```

**Bonus**: If freezegun is so meticulous to find `time.time()` references stored in module variables, why doesn't it patch `time.time()` used inside of `datetime.utcnow()`?

While searching through `sys.modules` it [deliberately omits](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/blob/0.3.12/freezegun/api.py#L623) `datetime` and `time` modules to not override the source functions and as a side effect `time.time` imported in `datetime` module stays not patched.

Comment: Awesome explanation - thank you! Clearly all bets are off in the face of relentless monkeypatching. :-)